# How to properly apply for a second time dup2()?

Tags: c, pipe, exec, dup2

Goal: having a program `alterna` that, according to an integer, particularly reads from STDIN_FILENO and writes on STDOUT_FILENO, write a program that accepts 3 arguments: a text file, two integers r1 and r2. The program generates two child processes that comunicate with a pipe. The first one executes `alterna` with r1 by reading from the text file given as argument, the second one executes `alterna` with r2 by reading from the output of the first child process. My solution is this, I just don't know how to properly write the second child process (blank), and I just wanted to apply some other `dup`s, but it didn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, void *argv[]){
  if(argc != 4)
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Inviare al programma il file di testo, r1 ed r2.\n", 49), exit(0);
  int input_file;
  size_t file_len;
  if((input_file = open(argv[1], O_RDWR)) < 0)
    perror("open"), exit(1);
  if((file_len = lseek(input_file, 0, SEEK_END)) < 0)
    perror("lseek"), exit(1);
  if((lseek(input_file, 0, SEEK_SET)) < 0)
    perror("lseek"), exit(1);
  char *r1 = argv[2];
  char *r2 = argv[3];
  char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * file_len);
  pid_t pid_p, pid_q;
  int status = 0;
  int fd[2];
  if((pipe(fd)) < 0)
    perror("pipe"), exit(1);
  if((pid_p = fork()) < 0)
    perror("fork"), exit(1);
  if(pid_p == 0){
    close(fd[0]);
    dup2(input_file, STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    execl("alterna", "alterna", r1, (char *) NULL);
    perror("execl"), exit(1);
  }
  else{
    waitpid(pid_p, &status, 0);
    if(!WIFEXITED(status))
      perror("p1"), exit(1);
    if((pid_q = fork()) < 0)
      perror("fork"), exit(1);
    if(pid_q == 0){
      close(fd[1]);

      /* BLANK */
      /*
      TODO:
      execute alterna by reading from fd[0]
      */

    }
    else{
      waitpid(pid_q, &status, 0);
      if(!WIFEXITED(status))
        perror("p2"), exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "Obviously, ... there are two processes".  Actually, it seems obvious that there ought to be 3 processes: 2 workers each running "alterna" and a coordinator (the parent).  IOW, nothing is "obvious".  Provide details, in particular how you are forking.  The dups need to happen in a child between fork and exec, and the devil is in the details of how that is set up.  Omitting the details makes it difficult to provide an answer.

Comment: Please include more code for X, including how the `dup2` calls relate to the `fork` calls. Are you trying to set up a bidirectional link between X and alterna? That would require two pipes because pipes are unidirectional.

Comment: Thanks, @WilliamPursell, included all infos.

Comment: @IanAbbott Now all details about the program "X" I wrote.

Comment: If you treat an incorrect number of arguments passed as an error, you should write an error message to stderr and exit non-zero.  If you treat it as a valid request for a usage statement, you should write a message to stdout and exit zero.  If you write a message to stdout and exit non-zero, your program is pathological.

Comment: Your 2nd fork needs to happen before the waitpid.  If you wait for the first process to complete, it may block.  You need both children to be executing at the same time.

Comment: @WilliamPursell ok, but the main problem is I have to write in the blank space something similiar to:
`dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);`
`execl("alterna", "alterna", r2, (char *) NULL);`
but it won't work because I have already wrote some dup2()s in the first child process.
How can I make it work?

Comment: @FueledByPizza Why wouldn't it work?  All of the previous `dup2`s were in the child and did not modify the parent at all.  As long as the parent hasn't closed any of the pipes before you `fork` the 2nd child, it should work.  (But you'll want to add error checking everywhere.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell yes, it works now! I just thought that `dup2()`s were affecting all the processes... The two lines i wrote in the previous comment just make the program work like i wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Your TODO will look basically like your first clause:

```
dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
close(fd[0]);
close(fd[1]);
execl("alterna", "alterna", r2, (char *) NULL);
perror("execl");
exit(1);
```

but you want to do this before the parent `wait`s on the first child.

Comment: The blank space is the second child (`pid_q`) process' body, and it starts after the parent `wait`ed the first child (`pid_p`) process.